# How do I unlock the sunday surprise on the 2013 Star Wars Advent Calendar?

Tags: star-wars, advent-calendar

I'm trying to enter the code on the back of door number 1 into the Lego Star Wars site but it doesn't work.  Does anyone know how / where to input the code?

Comment: This question is a little ambiguous, there's almost 2 questions being asked here, 1) how do I get the instructions, 2) how do I use the code. I believe the OP thinks that they're the same question. The gev answer below is the simple answer to the question #1, question #2 is what the duplicate says it is. I'm going  to edit the question to make it actually the question I have, and the duplicate question has, namely #1

Comment: I don't think he was asking how to build the figures everyday. He is asking where do you go to use the code in the figures to see the SUPRISE they have. I tried to find out where to input it online and had the same issue nowhere to put it. Help please

Answer (score 2):

I just found this website:

http://www.lego.com/en-us/starwars/games/web-games/advent-calendar

it has special stuff each day, the place you enter the code is the image of jango fett in the bottom middle.

Answer (score 1):

By "the build instructions" you mean how to assemble the day one model? It's right there on the flap. I doubt there's anything more to be had.

Comment: Well, now that the original post has been modified to hell and back, my 'Answer' makes no sense at all. :P

Answer (score 1):

The instructions to build it are on the back of the flap and to enter the code go to lego.com/starwars and go to fun and games or something. It mentions games. Anyways, there is a game called "Advent Calendar" and you click on a button torwards the bottom of the game screen (which you can make fullscreen) and enter the codes. They just unlock minifigures that you can be while playing the game.